# Where can i find the source of an Android's method?

Tags: android, methods

I have been searching for the source of an Android Method named `checkCallingOrSelfPermission`
It is used to validate an application's permissions.
I tried downloading Android's source but i couldn't found it there,
could you help? Thanks

Comment: If you're using Chrome, you could use [Android SDK Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-search/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin?hl=en) to show an Android class source while you're viewing its doc.

Comment: I'm not using Chrome right now, but i will install it to try it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always Chack grepcode.com 's Method search:
http://grepcode.com/search/?start=0&query=checkCallingOrSelfPermission&entity=method

PS.: Look for the ContextImpl Class to find the Implementation
Full Link: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/app/ContextImpl.java#ContextImpl.checkCallingOrSelfPermission%28java.lang.String%29 . You have to scroll down and wait until the class is fully loaded then you can use Cmd+F or View the raw Source.

Oh and if you already have the Source: `/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java`

Comment: I would say this is what i want, although i had searched in grepcode yesterday, i didn't see the ContextImpl Class :-P Thanks!

Comment: I knew, thanks, i just had to wait because you can't accept instantly, a message was saying 5 minutes wait.

Comment: Don't know where to put this: grepcode.com is not available anymore, eg. following above link gives `503 Service Unavailable`. Is there an alternative in place?

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidXref](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/search?q=&defs=checkCallingOrSelfPermission&refs=&path=&hist=&project=abi&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools) is another nice option to find code in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to find ContextImpl amongst every other class that exists in the AOSP codebase is through cs.android which is supported and maintained by Google themselves.

https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java;l=192;drc=master